# Closing delimiter as if inside array

Tags: conditionals, arrays, delimiters

Suppose that I have defined two commands

```
\newcommand\parens[1]{(\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1)\end{array}}
\newcommand\stmts[2]{\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1;#2\end{array}}
```

which attempt to allow for optional linebreaks while keeping the markup semantic.  Each of these commands works well on its own.  For example, `$\parens{X_1 \\ X_2}$` produces [image] and `$\stmts{Y_1}{\\ Y_2}$` produces [image].

However, in certain combinations, the two commands don't play nicely together.  For example, `$\parens{\stmts{Y_1}{\\ Y_2}}$` produces [image]

Instead, I would want the output to be [image], i.e., visually the same as if

```
$(\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      Y_1;
      \\ Y_2)
    \end{array}
  \end{array}$
```

had been used.  Is there any way to accomplish this without requiring the user to manually place the `)`?  In other words, can I redefine `\parens` and `\stmts` to give the desired behavior - without changing the user interface of those commands?

I suppose one solution might check if the next token is `)` and, if so, commute it with `\end{array}`.  But, in general, I would like a solution that works for all closing delimiters, not just `)`.  Even better would be a solution that works for arbitrary next tokens.

Here is some starter code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\parens[1]{(\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1)\end{array}}
\newcommand\stmts[2]{\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1;#2\end{array}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\enspace}l}
  \verb`\parens{\stmts{Y_1}{\\ Y_2}}` & $\parens{\stmts{Y_1}{\\ Y_2}}$ \\
  \\
  manual construction & $(\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                            \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                              Y_1;
                              \\ Y_2)
                            \end{array}
                          \end{array}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Since Werner asked for a more realistic use case, here is an example.  I would like the closing parenthesis to automatically appear after `\mathsf{closeR}`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\caseL[1]{\mathsf{caseL}}\lparen\rparen{\end{array}}%
  {
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { | } {#1}
    \seq_clear:N \l_tmpb_seq
    \seq_map_variable:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
      {
        \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { => } { \Rightarrow }
        \seq_put_right:NV \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_tl
      }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \mid }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \selectR { m m }
  {
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      \mathsf{selectR} \mskip\medmuskip #1 ;
      #2
    \end{array}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \waitL { m }
  {
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      \mathsf{waitL} ; #1
    \end{array}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \closeR { } { \mathsf{closeR} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$q_1 = \caseL{a => \selectR{b}{\\ \selectR{a}{q_0}} \\\mkern-8.5mu
            | b => q_1 \\\mkern-8.5mu
            | c => \waitL{\\ \selectR{b}{\\ \selectR{c}{\closeR}}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Avoid the `minimal` class, see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

Answer (score 2):

You can set conditionals depending on the construction sequence. Below we define two `\if`-conditions - `\ifparens` and `\ifstmts` which are set true at the start of each call. Then we can check to see whether one is nested inside the other, and place a `)` depending on that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifstmts
\newif\ifparens
\newcommand\parens[1]{\parenstrue(\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\ifstmts\else)\fi\end{array}\parensfalse\stmtsfalse}
\newcommand\stmts[2]{\stmtstrue\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1;#2\ifparens)\fi\end{array}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l@{\enspace}l}
  \verb`\parens{\stmts{Y_1}{\\ Y_2}}` & $\parens{\stmts{Y_1}{\\ Y_2}}$ \\
  \\
  manual construction & $(\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                            \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                              Y_1;
                              \\ Y_2)
                            \end{array}
                          \end{array}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clever idea!  My actual use case is more complex with multiple variations on `\parens` and `\stmts` that interact, but I think I should be able to adapt your idea to my setting.  One disadvantage is that code from `\parens` invades `\stmts`so that the code is not modular.  I take it that there is no way to look ahead to the class of symbol until that symbol is typeset?

Comment: @HenryDeYoung: There are probably other possibilities. Provide a complex example and one can see what is possible.

Comment: I've added a more complex example.  Thanks for your help, Werner!